# creating a custom redirecting page

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to make a page like 
`www.example.com/redirect.php`

above page must redirect to another page like 
`www.google.com`

But whenever I open `www.example.com/redirect.php?changeurl=www.yahoo.com`
from now onwards www.example.com/redirect.php 
page should start redirecting to yahoo.com

if `changeurl=youtube.com`
from now onwards
the page `www.example.com/redirect.php` must star redirecting to `youtube.com`

How can I do that without using SQL database, only by using a single file "redirect.php"

Please ask if you need more information about this question

Answer (score 0):

First off you should at least have some code already written.

But try using this:

**redirect.php:**

```
<?php
if(!file_exists("redirect_url.txt")) {
    $createfile= fopen("redirect_url.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "https://www.google.com";
    fwrite($createfile, $txt);
    fclose($createfile);    
}

if(isset($_GET['changeurl'])) {
    $editfile= fopen("redirect_url.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $_GET['changeurl'];
    fwrite($editfile, $txt);
    fclose($editfile);
    header("Location: " . $_GET['changeurl']);
} else {
    $myfile = fopen("redirect_url.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $url = fgets($myfile);
    fclose($myfile);
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

Also make sure in the `?changeurl` You always use `http://` or `https://`, Since you are not using a database you can use a `.txt` file.

Comment: in this way, the page will redirect to custom URL only when the changeurl is specified but what I want is at first the page was redirecting to, suppose google.com but at the moment when i give changeurl a value, from now onwards the the url www.example.com/redirect.php must start redirecting to the new page

Comment: @SidhantSood I do not understand, And as I specified You should already have of researched it or have a least a little code of what you have tried.

Comment: i am at the same point what you have answered. but i have to save change url in the page itself, so that next time when i open redirect.php it automatically redirect me to last specified change url

Comment: @SidhantSood Try now